# Is it possible to resolve a hostname from an IP address without DNS?

Tags: hostname

I have a question , can i ping an ip and return hostname without dns using or ip mapping ?

Maybe from the ARP cache .

Answer (score 2):

No,  well certainly not with ping, because ping isn't a name resolving service. Anyway, if you ping a host-name, DNS is used first to translate into an IP.

You could connect to a service running on a port (a website on 80 for example) that replies with a packet that includes host-name.  Some protocols can also disclose the host-name during the connection conversation (SMTP for example) .

So, if you're on the same network segment (depending on routers and switches between) you *can* get host information through arp requests, or on some protocols (netbios)